# How to identify AppendMenu MF_POPUP Menu in the WindowProcedure?

Tags: c, winapi, win32gui

I'm getting confused.

**MF_POPUP

0x00000010L**

> Specifies that the menu item opens a drop-down menu or submenu. **The
> `uIDNewItem` parameter specifies a handle to the drop-down menu or
> submenu.** This flag is used to add a menu name to a menu bar, or a menu
> item that opens a submenu to a drop-down menu, submenu, or shortcut
> menu.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-appendmenua)

Yes, but how do we now specify the **uID** of the **Menu** and refer to it in the WindowProcedure,
if the **`uIDNewItem`** parameter is now **a handle to the drop-down menu or submenu**.

Comment: The popup menu is handled by the system for you. Your window procedure need get involved. When a user selects a menu item from the popup menu, the window procedure receives an appropriate [WM_COMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command) message.

Comment: You won't receive any `WM_COMMAND` messages for a `MF_POPUP` menu item, so there is no ID to look for.  However, you can receive `WM_MENUCOMMAND` and `WM_MENUCHAR` messages instead, which will give you the `HMENU` of the submenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple code sample you can refer,

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define EXIT_ID 1
#define SUB_ID 2

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HMENU hMenubar = CreateMenu();
        HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu(); //file is a regular menu.. Exit is a regular sub-menu..
        HMENU hDisplayMenu = CreatePopupMenu(); //display is a popup-menu because it has children.

        AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFileMenu, "File");
        AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hDisplayMenu, "Display"); 
        AppendMenu(hDisplayMenu, MF_STRING, SUB_ID, "Sub");
        AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, EXIT_ID, "Exit"); 
        SetMenu(hwnd, hMenubar);
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case SUB_ID:
            MessageBox(hwnd, "You click Sub menu", " ", MB_OK);
            break;
        case EXIT_ID:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;   
};

HINSTANCE hinst;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevinstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {
    HWND hwnd;

    hinst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    // create a window class:
    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hinst;
    wc.lpszClassName = "win32";

    // register class with operating system:
    RegisterClass(&wc);
    // create and show window:
    hwnd = CreateWindow("win32", "My program", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL, 0, 0, 1000, 800, NULL, NULL, hinst, NULL);
    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    MSG msg = {};

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

}
```

Debug:

[image: 1]

`EXIT_ID` and `SUB_ID` are the uID of the submenu. You need to define them manually.

```
#define EXIT_ID 1
#define SUB_ID 2
```

**Updated:**

You can use [WM_MENUSELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-menuselect) to get the handle to the menu that is clicked and compare their hmenus.

> Sent to a menu's owner window when the user selects a menu item.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HMENU hMenubar;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        hMenubar = CreateMenu();
        HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu(); //file is a regular menu.. Exit is a regular sub-menu..        
        
        AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFileMenu, L"File");
        SetMenu(hWnd, hMenubar);
    }
    break;
    case WM_MENUSELECT:
    {
        HMENU hmenu = (HMENU)lParam;     
        if (hmenu == hMenubar)
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"You click main menu", L" ", MB_OK);
        }
  
    }
    break;
    ...
```

Like this,

[image]

Comment: The question is mostly regarding the "File" Menu itself: how can we handle and react to the pressing of the "File" Menu button, just like the menu entries and submenus in your example.

Comment: @user3789797 Sorry, I misunderstand your means. As the doc said that,  if the `uFlags` parameter is set to `MF_POPUP`, a handle to the drop-down menu or submenu. In other words, you cannot set the UID separately under the `MF_POPUP` style. I want to know why you need to handle the click of the FILE button separately.

Comment: It's more of personal exercise of consistency in the design of win32 programming. To have an answer under the belt if ever needed. It's really not healthy or useful to have unanswered questions in the back of your head. Although this might help with some ideas in the future like better Drag N Drop support on some applications or unique UI that's more self evident. Handling of hovering and temporal helper popup window - could also put to use with this kind of Menu handling. In short: lots of uses that could be practical and truly useful.